# How to run a Karate Feature file after a Gatling simulation completes

Tags: karate

I have two Karate Feature files

1. One for creating a user (CreateUser.feature)
2. One for getting a count of users created (GetUserCount.feature)

I have additionally one Gatling Scala file

1. This calls CreateUser.feature with rampUser(100) over (5 seconds)

This works perfect.  What i'd like to know is how can I call GetUserCount.feature after Gatling finishes it's simulation?  It must only be called one time to get the final created user count.  What are my options and how can I implement them?

Comment: That's a heck of a question title! Are you building software or an action movie? :P

Comment: A movie about testing software.  Rambo: He's testing software now and he means business :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option is use the [Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api) to run a single feature in the Gatling simulation.

```
Runner.runFeature("classpath:mock/feeder.feature", null, false)
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Any plans to support tags in the runFeature( ) method? (eg "classpath:mock/feeder.feature@mytag=rambo")   I group my endpoints into .feature files and separate them by tags to call each separately.

Comment: @user1701153 does it not already work that way in `runFeature()` if not, please file a bug